# Reduce frame rate

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way to reduce the game `framerate` from 30 to 25 fps on the `iPhone`? I'm porting a Flash game created at **25 fps** and exporting the sprites with this frame rate but animations are not shown as correctly as they should.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, straight out of the box :

```
animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:.04];
```

with 40 ms delay, that should come real close to 25 fps (rendered animation) while the rest of the game is clocking full bore at 60 fps (if you don't have lag issues elsewhere)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can change your animation interval in your `App Delegate` with the following snippet in your `didFinishLaunching` method :

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/25];
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT :**

Could this link provide you more information about how to deal with that ?

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices

Comment: I've tried this but minimum frame rate is 30 fps. I cannot go below this value.

Comment: Mmmmm, I see... Is it a limitation of the iPhone ? I'll have a look and complete my answer if I find something

Answer (score -3):

Well, at last the solution is by another way.

1. Kept the framerate to 1.0/60.0

What you need to do for animating the spritesheet slowest is to add the frame more than once to the animation array.

```
NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
            for(int i =  _spriteMetadata.spriteInitFrame; i <= _spriteMetadata.spriteEndFrame; ++i) 
{
NSString *spriteFrameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _spriteMetadata.spriteBaseName, index];

                for (int i=0; i<2; i++)
                {
                    [walkAnimFrames addObject:
                     [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:spriteFrameName]];
                }
            }
```

It's not very orthodox but it works! :)

Thanks for your help Andy!